# No address associated with the host server

Tags: server

Please help me with this.  I am getting "No address associated with the Host Name" error when I run "sudo apt-get update" command from the console

Comment: see [the answer](http://askubuntu.com/questions/199541/solving-the-ubuntu-12-04-update-error-5-no-address-associated-with-hostname)

Comment: I think this is to do something todo with name resolution.  I can ping yahoo ip address but can not ping Yaho thru its name... Any Idea?

Answer (score 0):

Check your /etc/resolv.conf

At least one from "nameserver x.x.x.x" ipaddrs should answer to pings.

If none, then try to ping 8.8.8.8

If 8.8.8.8 answers, then add it to resolv.conf:

```
echo nameserver 8.8.8.8 >> /etc/resolv.conf
```

If not, then check your internet connection.

Also check your APT sources:

```
grep -rv '^$' /etc/apt/sources.list* | grep -v ':#'
```

May be they are invalid and not reachable.